# How to pass parameter in PostgresOperator Airflow using for loop

Tags: python, sql, airflow, postgres-operator

I am using PostgresOperator and I want to pass table name suffix to my SQL query so when it queries the data, it reads dynamically from the for loop iteration

```
for country in countries:

matchTimeStamp = ShortCircuitOperator(task_id='Match_Updated_dates_{}'.format(country), provide_context=True,
                                      python_callable=match_dates,op_kwargs={'key1': country}, default_args=default_args)
```

So as you can see I have passed .format(country) in task_id. I want to do similar stuff by passing country name like in the below SQL statement but seems like Airflow doesn't like it. Please suggest a correct way
As at the end I have passed .format country at the end of my SQL statement

```
import_redshift_table = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='copy_data_from_redshift_{}'.format(country),
    postgres_conn_id='postgres_default',
    sql='''
        unload ('select * from angaza_public_{}.accounts')
        to 's3://mygluecrawlerbucket/angaza_accounts/to_be_processed/anagaza_{}.csv'
        credentials 'aws_access_key_id=AWSDD****HHJJJJ;aws_secret_access_key=ABCDEFDHPASSEORD/JmlGjyEQMVOBme'
        DELIMITER ','
    HEADER
    PARALLEL OFF
'''.format(country))
```

----- Update, I was able to find a solution-------- I added an extra coutry key word  in the .format(country,country)

```
    import_redshift_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='copy_data_from_redshift_{}'.format(country),
        postgres_conn_id='postgres_default',
        sql='''
                unload ('select * from angaza_public_{}.accounts')
                to 's3://mygluecrawlerbucket/angaza_accounts/to_be_processed/anagaza_{}.csv'
                credentials 'aws_access_key_id=AKIA6J7OV4FRSYH6DIXL;aws_secret_access_key=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'
                DELIMITER ','
            HEADER
            PARALLEL OFF
        '''.format(country, country))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Airflow doesn't like it"? What error do you get?

Comment: Broken DAG: [/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/fullPipelineDag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/fullPipelineDag.py", line 123, in <module>
    '''.format(country))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis that is making it not work. Also, I think f-string is more readable than .format. With this, it would work:

```
import_redshift_table = PostgresOperator(
    task_id=f'copy_data_from_redshift_{country}',
    postgres_conn_id='postgres_default',  # this is not necessary if its the default
    sql=f"""
        unload ('select * from angaza_public_{country}.accounts')
        to 's3://mygluecrawlerbucket/angaza_accounts/to_be_processed/anagaza_{country}.csv'
        credentials 'aws_access_key_id=AWSDD****HHJJJJ;aws_secret_access_key=ABCDEFDHPASSEORD/JmlGjyEQMVOBme'
        DELIMITER ','
    HEADER
    PARALLEL OFF
"""
```

By the way, it is a good practice to make unloads from Redshift using an IAM Role instead of credentials, so that they don't appear in the logs.

Comment: I tried honestly first that way but didn't work for me. Update I was able to solve the above issue.  My Solution . Also thanks for your solution I can now use it in a diff way also.

Comment: have you used s3keySenor, I was woonderinng if they have prefix parameter thing after the bucket name ?